# How to Install geotools by gradle in android studio 3.1.2

Tags: android, geotools

I wan to use geotools in my project so i've added geotools lib in my repositories project gradle :

```
 allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main" }
        maven { url "http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/" }
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

I have a module called map and i haved added this dependencies to this gradle:

```
dependencies {
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    api 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.6.5'
    api 'com.github.MKergall:osmbonuspack:6.4'
    api 'com.vividsolutions:jts-core:1.14.0'
    api 'com.vividsolutions:jts-io:1.14.0'
    api 'org.orbisgis:cts:1.5.1', {
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
    }
    api 'org.jdom:jdom:1.1.3'
    api 'org.geotools:gt-metadata:19.0'
}
```

When i make this project i got this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':commision12:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\User
s\TazikA\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.geotools\gt-opengis\19.0\f5a2e7f75e0883bfd319c57d935fb65a5c42e232\gt-opengis-19.0.jar
```

I have added `multiDexEnabled true` in defultConfig and `api 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'` to my module gradle.

Someone have any idea that where is my mistake?

Comment: Use `api 'org.geotools:gt-metadata:18.3'` instead of `api 'org.geotools:gt-metadata:19.0'`.

Comment: I used api 'org.geotools:gt-metadata:19.0' i try to use your version @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: I added gt-metadata:18:3 I have got this error: http://codepad.org/JPtZJx3X

Comment: For dex issue take a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/33430306/3395198. Create Application class.

Comment: `Clean-Rebuild-Restart IDE`

Comment: I do clean and rebuild my project and finally i restarted my IDE but still got error. One day I wasted and nothing is work @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: I'm pretty sure most of GeoTools won't work on Android - see https://github.com/jodygarnett/geotools-andriod and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155885/how-to-show-maps-using-geotools-in-android

Comment: @IanTurton yep dude i understand that it won't work on android so i gave up . thanks to you and IntelliJAmiya for helping.